# FreeRadius + AD + static ip assignment

Tags: ldap, freeradius

Hi I need help with assigning static IP addresses from Active Directory
I'm using FreeRadius version 3.0.10

I understand, that I should use LDAP atribute mapping, but with no success.

Trying to do something like

```
update reply {
        Framed-IP-Address = &msRADIUSFramedIPAddress
}
```

also, msRADIUSFramedIPAddress is binary, so there should be some conversion. 
I found this example where right side was

```
=&Atribute-of-type-Octets
```

but not sure if this would do something or just should a use some special atribute

While trying to run radius -X the msRADIUSFramedIPAddress is unknown atribute

I'm just so lost in this mapping, reading and trying several days.

I would really appreciate help.

Thank you

Juraj Lehotsky

Answer (score 1):

In v3.1.x and I believe v3.0.x it will attempt an autocast between the types.

So in

mods-available/ldap

```
ldap {
    update {
        reply:Framed-IP-Address := 'msRADIUSFramedIPAddress'
    }
}
```

Should work.

If not you'll need to do

mods-available/ldap

```
ldap {
    update {
        Tmp-Octets-0 := 'msRADIUSFramedIPAddress'
    }
}
```

sites-available/default

```
authorize {
    ldap
    if (&Tmp-Octets-0) {
        update reply {
            Framed-IP-Address := &Tmp-Octets-0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but nothing works. First one is working fine until i try to join the network, then it says, that it cannot parse the value (-1062731454) which should be my IP. Second one don't gave any error, but my condition after LDAP, if(!ok) is valid, so it's not working as it should. Also the final Framed-IP-Address is in hexa and very long hexa.

Comment: Framed-IP-Address is like 0x2d31303632373331343534 where its looking like octa except the start which is confusing me